# colcon build fails humble

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i run colcon build, it fails because there is a syntax error. But i deleted the file containing the syntax error, moveMotor.py.  That file used to be in :

```
~/Documents/my_robot/ros_ws/src/test1/test1
```

When i run colcon build, it errors because it finds that file in

```
~/Documents/my_robot/ros_ws/install/test1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/test1/moveMotor.py
```

When i delete it and run colcon build again, that file is regenerated, and colcon build again fails!
what do i do?

i double checked that my package.xml and setup.py make no reference to moveMotor

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402185/colcon-build-fails-humble/) by [r_gerson](https://answers.ros.org/users/106098/r_gerson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2022-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i fixed the issue by removing the build, install, and log directories

---

Originally posted by [r_gerson](https://answers.ros.org/users/106098/r_gerson/) with karma: 36 on 2022-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1